# How to correctly set fonts rendering in ArchLinux/LXDE?

Tags: arch-linux, fonts, lxde

I've just installed ArchLinux and LXDE, everything is working fine but fonts rendering is not optimal. Reading the [wiki about font configuration](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Font_configuration) and using external source of information, I've build the following **/etc/fonts/fonts.conf** file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
  <match target="font">
     <edit mode="assign" name="rgba">
       <const>rgb</const>
     </edit>
     <edit mode="assign" name="hinting">
       <bool>true</bool>
     </edit>
     <edit mode="assign" name="hintstyle">
       <const>hintfull</const>
     </edit>
     <edit mode="assign" name="antialias">
       <bool>true</bool>
     </edit>
     <edit mode="assign" name="lcdfilter">
       <const>lcddefault</const>
     </edit> 
  </match>
</fontconfig>
```

Despite this, the font rendering is still not optimal
[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you use `lxappearance`?

Comment: Yes, with `lxappearance-obconf` plugin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've found the solution: The index of X font files was not created.

I discover this looking at the `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` log file.

```
$ grep /fonts /var/log/Xorg.0.log.old

[    13.492] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/Type1/" does not exist.
[    13.493] (WW) `fonts.dir' not found (or not valid) in "/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/".
[    13.493]    (Run 'mkfontdir' on "/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/").
[    13.493] (WW) `fonts.dir' not found (or not valid) in "/usr/share/fonts/75dpi/".
[    13.494]    (Run 'mkfontdir' on "/usr/share/fonts/75dpi/").
    /usr/share/fonts/misc/,
    /usr/share/fonts/TTF/,
    /usr/share/fonts/OTF/
```

I then run `mkfontdir` on `/usr/share/fonts/75dpi` and `/usr/share/fonts/100dpi` and that was solved.

Comment: In my case I needed to restart Xorg also. Thanks!